# Cassandra 1.2.6: unable to bootstrap on Mac OS

Tags: java, cassandra

I've followed the "Getting Started" steps [here](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted), but when I ran `bin/cassandra -f`, I received a runtime exception "No other nodes seen! Unable to bootstrap". I've also tried the DataStax version but it didn't work either.

The following is the log I got after running the command:

```
xss =  -ea -javaagent:./bin/../lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms2G -Xmx2G -Xmn200M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
 INFO 17:55:03,552 Logging initialized
 INFO 17:55:03,572 JVM vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.6.0_51
 INFO 17:55:03,573 Heap size: 2126512128/2126512128
 INFO 17:55:03,573 Classpath: ./bin/../conf:./bin/../build/classes/main:./bin/../build/classes/thrift:./bin/../lib/antlr-3.2.jar:./bin/../lib/apache-cassandra-1.2.6.jar:./bin/../lib/apache-cassandra-clientutil-1.2.6.jar:./bin/../lib/apache-cassandra-thrift-1.2.6.jar:./bin/../lib/avro-1.4.0-fixes.jar:./bin/../lib/avro-1.4.0-sources-fixes.jar:./bin/../lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:./bin/../lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar:./bin/../lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:./bin/../lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:./bin/../lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.jar:./bin/../lib/guava-13.0.1.jar:./bin/../lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.2.jar:./bin/../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:./bin/../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:./bin/../lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar:./bin/../lib/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar:./bin/../lib/jline-1.0.jar:./bin/../lib/jna-3.5.2.jar:./bin/../lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:./bin/../lib/libthrift-0.7.0.jar:./bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:./bin/../lib/lz4-1.1.0.jar:./bin/../lib/metrics-core-2.0.3.jar:./bin/../lib/netty-3.5.9.Final.jar:./bin/../lib/platform-3.5.2.jar:./bin/../lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:./bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar:./bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar:./bin/../lib/snakeyaml-1.6.jar:./bin/../lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar:./bin/../lib/snaptree-0.1.jar:./bin/../lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar
 INFO 17:55:03,661 JNA link failure, one or more native method will be unavailable.
 INFO 17:55:03,675 Loading settings from file:/opt/apache-cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
 INFO 17:55:04,060 Data files directories: [/var/lib/cassandra/data]
 INFO 17:55:04,060 Commit log directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
 INFO 17:55:04,061 DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
 INFO 17:55:04,061 disk_failure_policy is stop
 INFO 17:55:04,067 Global memtable threshold is enabled at 676MB
 INFO 17:55:04,215 Not using multi-threaded compaction
 INFO 17:55:04,578 Initializing key cache with capacity of 100 MBs.
 INFO 17:55:04,587 Scheduling key cache save to each 14400 seconds (going to save all keys).
 INFO 17:55:04,588 Initializing row cache with capacity of 0 MBs and provider org.apache.cassandra.cache.SerializingCacheProvider
 INFO 17:55:04,594 Scheduling row cache save to each 0 seconds (going to save all keys).
 INFO 17:55:04,780 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_keyspaces/system-schema_keyspaces-ic-2 (224 bytes)
 INFO 17:55:04,826 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_keyspaces/system-schema_keyspaces-ic-1 (225 bytes)
 INFO 17:55:04,848 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-ic-1 (4612 bytes)
 INFO 17:55:04,852 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-ic-2 (4610 bytes)
 INFO 17:55:04,866 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columns/system-schema_columns-ic-2 (4347 bytes)
 INFO 17:55:04,869 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columns/system-schema_columns-ic-1 (4347 bytes)
 INFO 17:55:04,899 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-ic-6 (84 bytes)
 INFO 17:55:04,904 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-ic-5 (390 bytes)
 INFO 17:55:04,904 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-ic-7 (238 bytes)
 INFO 17:55:05,432 completed pre-loading (3 keys) key cache.
 INFO 17:55:05,441 Replaying /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-2-1372783491824.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-2-1372783491825.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-2-1372783491826.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-2-1372783491827.log
 INFO 17:55:05,452 Replaying /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-2-1372783491824.log
 INFO 17:55:05,533 Finished reading /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-2-1372783491824.log
 INFO 17:55:05,534 Replaying /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-2-1372783491825.log
 INFO 17:55:05,536 Finished reading /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-2-1372783491825.log
 INFO 17:55:05,557 Replaying /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-2-1372783491826.log
 INFO 17:55:05,558 Finished reading /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-2-1372783491826.log
 INFO 17:55:05,558 Replaying /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-2-1372783491827.log
 INFO 17:55:05,558 Finished reading /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-2-1372783491827.log
 INFO 17:55:05,578 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-local@69635270(52/52 serialized/live bytes, 4 ops)
 INFO 17:55:05,615 Writing Memtable-local@69635270(52/52 serialized/live bytes, 4 ops)
 INFO 17:55:05,630 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-schema_keyspaces@1007379802(251/251 serialized/live bytes, 8 ops)
 INFO 17:55:05,631 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-schema_columns@271259266(24717/24717 serialized/live bytes, 398 ops)
 INFO 17:55:05,632 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-schema_columnfamilies@2094184728(22187/22187 serialized/live bytes, 369 ops)
 INFO 17:55:05,648 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-ic-8-Data.db (83 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1372784105314, position=142)
 INFO 17:55:05,666 Writing Memtable-schema_keyspaces@1007379802(251/251 serialized/live bytes, 8 ops)
 INFO 17:55:05,678 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_keyspaces/system-schema_keyspaces-ic-3-Data.db (220 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1372784105314, position=142)
 INFO 17:55:05,680 Writing Memtable-schema_columns@271259266(24717/24717 serialized/live bytes, 398 ops)
 INFO 17:55:05,713 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columns/system-schema_columns-ic-3-Data.db (4306 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1372784105314, position=142)
 INFO 17:55:05,714 Writing Memtable-schema_columnfamilies@2094184728(22187/22187 serialized/live bytes, 369 ops)
 INFO 17:55:05,737 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-ic-3-Data.db (4593 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1372784105314, position=142)
 INFO 17:55:05,738 Log replay complete, 13 replayed mutations
 INFO 17:55:06,054 Cassandra version: 1.2.6
 INFO 17:55:06,054 Thrift API version: 19.36.0
 INFO 17:55:06,055 CQL supported versions: 2.0.0,3.0.4 (default: 3.0.4)
 INFO 17:55:06,124 Loading persisted ring state
 INFO 17:55:06,128 Starting up server gossip
 INFO 17:55:06,144 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-local@796902479(251/251 serialized/live bytes, 9 ops)
 INFO 17:55:06,144 Writing Memtable-local@796902479(251/251 serialized/live bytes, 9 ops)
 INFO 17:55:06,156 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-ic-9-Data.db (238 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1372784105314, position=53949)
 INFO 17:55:06,167 Compacting [SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-ic-7-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-ic-9-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-ic-8-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-ic-5-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-ic-6-Data.db')]
 INFO 17:55:06,261 Compacted 5 sstables to [/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-ic-10,].  1,033 bytes to 395 (  1 export SVN_EDITOR=vim
~38% of original) in 76ms = 0.004957MB/s.  5 total rows, 1 unique.  Row merge counts were {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:1, }
 INFO 17:55:06,336 Starting Messaging Service on port 7000
 WARN 17:55:06,387 Detected previous bootstrap failure; retrying
 INFO 17:55:06,389 JOINING: waiting for ring information
 INFO 17:55:36,416 JOINING: schema complete, ready to bootstrap
 INFO 17:55:36,419 JOINING: getting bootstrap token
ERROR 17:55:36,421 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: No other nodes seen!  Unable to bootstrap.If you intended to start a single-node cluster, you should make sure your broadcast_address (or listen_address) is listed as a seed.  Otherwise, you need to determine why the seed being contacted has no knowledge of the rest of the cluster.  Usually, this can be solved by giving all nodes the same seed list.
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.BootStrapper.getBootstrapSource(BootStrapper.java:154)
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.BootStrapper.getBalancedToken(BootStrapper.java:135)
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.BootStrapper.getBootstrapTokens(BootStrapper.java:115)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:666)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:554)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:451)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:342)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:441)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:484)
java.lang.RuntimeException: No other nodes seen!  Unable to bootstrap.If you intended to start a single-node cluster, you should make sure your broadcast_address (or listen_address) is listed as a seed.  Otherwise, you need to determine why the seed being contacted has no knowledge of the rest of the cluster.  Usually, this can be solved by giving all nodes the same seed list.
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.BootStrapper.getBootstrapSource(BootStrapper.java:154)
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.BootStrapper.getBalancedToken(BootStrapper.java:135)
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.BootStrapper.getBootstrapTokens(BootStrapper.java:115)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:666)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:554)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:451)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:342)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:441)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:484)
Exception encountered during startup: No other nodes seen!  Unable to bootstrap.If you intended to start a single-node cluster, you should make sure your broadcast_address (or listen_address) is listed as a seed.  Otherwise, you need to determine why the seed being contacted has no knowledge of the rest of the cluster.  Usually, this can be solved by giving all nodes the same seed list.
ERROR 17:55:36,424 Exception in thread Thread[StorageServiceShutdownHook,5,main]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.stopRPCServer(StorageService.java:321)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.shutdownClientServers(StorageService.java:370)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.access$000(StorageService.java:88)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService$1.runMayThrow(StorageService.java:519)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: Are you trying to set up a single node environment? If not can you paste the `listen_address` settings from your various cassandra.yaml files?

Comment: Yup, I'm trying to set up a single node environment. Here's what I have in .yaml `listen_address: localhost`.

Comment: What is `seeds` set to in the yaml?  You need to have this host set as a seed otherwise it will try to bootstrap.

Comment: My `seeds` is 127.0.0.1, after changing the `listen_address` from localhost to 127.0.0.1, the startup completed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Richard pointed out, `seeds` has to be the same as the `listen_address` in a single-node environment. The reason that caused the bootstrap exception was that remote login on my Mac was turned on, so `localhost` returns the local IP instead of `127.0.0.1`. Turning off remote login solved the problem.